# Custom sorting mat-table when each row is represented by FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `mat-table` where the `datasource` is a `MatTableDataSource<FormGroup>`. The `FormGroup` that represents each row is obviously is a `FormArray` property of another `FormGroup`. So, the form's schema is roughly this:

`FormGroup(persons: FormArray(FormGroup[firstName, lastName]))`

I was able to override the filtering function by:

`this.dataSource.filterPredicate = someCustomFilterFunction`

However, if I try to override the sorting with:
`this.dataSource.data.sort((a: FromGroup, b: FormGroup): number...)`

My form gets all confused. In fact, it looks like one of the form controls thinks it's another form control in another row.

Is there no way to sort this without me having to recreate the entire sort in already sorted state?

Comment: Please share your code and then only able to answer your question

Comment: Looks like there isn't a good way of sorting items in the FormArray: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164800/what-is-the-ideal-way-to-sort-a-formarray-object-in-angular-2

Comment: Just found my answer... It's NOT possible to sort it like a regular array (LAST paragraph in FormArray api doc): "Adding or removing controls from a form array
To change the controls in the array, use the push, insert, removeAt or clear methods in FormArray itself. These methods ensure the controls are properly tracked in the form's hierarchy. Do not modify the array of AbstractControls used to instantiate the FormArray directly, as that result in strange and unexpected behavior such as broken change detection."

Answer (score 1):

Really I'm not pretty sure when you say "the FormGroup that represents each row is obviously is a FormArray property of another FormGroup". If you has a MatDataSource you has **NOT** a FormArray of FormGroup, just an Array of FormGroups

In that case, the only you need is provide a custom sort function. Remember that you're comparing FormGroups:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.sortData = (data: FormGroup[], sort: MatSort) => {
      //in "data" you has the array of FormGroup
      //in sort.direction you has "asc,"desc" or ""
      //in sort.active you has the column you clicked
      const factor =
        sort.direction == "asc" ? 1 : sort.direction == "desc" ? -1 : 0;
      if (factor) {
        data = data.sort((a: FormGroup, b: FormGroup) => {
          const aValue = a.get(sort.active) ? a.get(sort.active).value : null;
          const bValue = a.get(sort.active) ? b.get(sort.active).value : null;
          return aValue > bValue ? factor : aValue < bValue ? -factor : 0;
        });
      }
      return data;
    };
  }
```

NOTE: I supose a dataSource an array of FormGroup create as

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(
    ELEMENT_DATA.map(
      x =>
        new FormGroup({
          position: new FormControl(x.position),
          name: new FormControl(x.name),
          weight: new FormControl(x.weight),
          symbol: new FormControl(x.symbol)
        })
    )
  );
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6yzpgn?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts)

**Update** if you want a formArray remember that the dataSource is about yourFormArray.controls, some like

```
  myArray=new FormArray(...)
  //see that dataSource is MatDataSource(this.myArray.controls)
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.myArray.controls);
```

Comment: Just found my answer... It's NOT possible to sort it like a regular array (LAST paragraph in FormArray api doc): "Adding or removing controls from a form array
To change the controls in the array, use the push, insert, removeAt or clear methods in FormArray itself. These methods ensure the controls are properly tracked in the form's hierarchy. Do not modify the array of AbstractControls used to instantiate the FormArray directly, as that result in strange and unexpected behavior such as broken change detection."

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful implementing a case insensitive sort without knowing much about MatSort. I just added .toLowerCase() on the aValue/bValue